# I have some simple JavaScript code, and I want to turn it into a popup extension. How do I do this?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I tried creating a manifest that leads to a popup.js file and put the following code in that file but the popup showed up as just a white square.

**This is My JavaScript code**

```
fill(0, 0, 0);
ellipse(200, 200, 375, 375);
fill(60, 0, 255);
triangle(200, 104, 280, 280, 120, 280);
fill(255, 255, 255);
var answer = floor(random(1, 20));

if (answer === 1) {
    text("As I see it,", 171, 200);
    text("yes", 189, 229); 
}
else if (answer === 2) {
    text("Ask again", 171, 200);
    text("later", 189, 229); 

...

else {
    text("You may", 175, 200);
    text("rely on it", 177, 229); 
}
```

**This is my manifest**
(most likely needs some editing)

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "8 ball popup",
  "version": "0.1",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Your fortune will appear here."
  }
}
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file/950146#950146

Answer (score 1):

Posting your manifest would help.

However, I recommend you checking the [browerAction docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction).

Basically you also need to create an HTML page, and link your js file to it.

Comment: I tried following the code on the docs, but when I click on the extension, a small white square is showing up underneath the icon, and nothing else.

Comment: I could not reproduce though. The white square underneath the icon is probably something that `browserAction.setBadgeText` could generate. Since you did not post your complete js or HTML code it's hard to tell. Probably you have some event handler for `chrome.browserAction.onClicked`  (in background.js? Is the manifest you posted a complete one?) @GangstaGaming